# How clicking barItem in Navigation Bar will bring new content page

Tags: xamarin.forms

[![enter image description here][1]][1]This is the MainPage which has a navigation Bar that contains 4 barItems.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="CheckList"
             x:Class="mmy.View.MainPage">    

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon1.png" Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon2.png" Priority="1" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon3.png" Priority="2" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon4.png" Priority="3" />

    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="MainPage"/>             
        </StackLayout>        

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


  The Navigation Bar will look like below:

        -------------------------------------------------------
        Main      barItem1  |  barItem2  | barItem3 | barItem4
        -------------------------------------------------------

         Item1_Content
```

Say , I have 4 bar items in the Navigation bar

I want to do the following:

1. When user click barItem2 ,

a)  it will bring in a Item2_Content which will replace the Item1_Content. ( I m not sure there is such UI )

b) the barItem (1 to 4 ) still remain in the navigation bar.

Is this doable?

Can you help me how to implement such user requirement?

Thanks

**Update:**
--(1) - start at P1 :

```
private async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  NavigationPage NP = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
  {
       BarBackgroundColor = Color.White,
       BarTextColor = Color.DarkGray
 };
}
```

--(2) I created a new page call RepairSvc for (3)

--(3) At MainPage : it has a navigation bar from (1)

Click the  Icon="itemIcon1.png"

```
   <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon1.png" Command="Item1Command" Priority="0" />

     Code Behind :

     [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
           public ICommand Item1Command { get; private set; }

            public MainPage()
            {
               InitializeComponent();

                this.Item1Command = new Command((sender) =>
                {
                    Navigation.PushAsync(new RepairSvc());
                });           
            }

        }
```

Comment: this is a really weird navigation pattern.  It sounds like they really want a TabbedPage

Comment: @jason, please refer to the pic just uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

assign a command to your toolbar

```
<ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon1.png" Priority="0" Command="Item1Command" />
```

in your codebehind

```
   this.Item1Command = new Command((sender) =>
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage());
        });
    }

    public ICommand Item1Command { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Just added an update. I could not get it working. What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: is your page already contained within a NavigationPage?  Are you sure that the command is firing when you click the toolbar item?

Comment: The Update showed what I did. MainPage is like the Pic I showed above has many barItems with a single label inside StackLayout.  The Page in NavigationPage is MainPage when start fom (1). The RepairSvc Page should show once I click the icon. Please correct my mistake as I am very new to Xamarin Form.

Comment: at a glance, that looks correct.  Have you verified (with the debugger) that your command is executed when you click on it?